# MS Edge - CSS transition is not working properly

Tags: css, internet-explorer, css-transitions, microsoft-edge

I am trying to make a simple **pure CSS slider** for the FB page widget. The thing is that the code works for all of the major browsers exept MS Edge and IE.

---

```
.slider {
  -webkit-transition: right 1s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: right 1s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: right 1s ease-in-out;
  transition: right 1s ease-in-out;
}
```

Everytime when I move the mouse cursor to the FB iframe the transition is cancelled. I tried to add the overlay and `pointer-events` as a iframe's parent but effect is the same.

### [image: Gif demonstrate the issue]

Is this the MS Edge bug or I am doing something wrong?

I am giving working [CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bLoXWr).

---

**EDIT:** I don't wanna use jQuery. As I mentioned before it has to be **pure CSS** animation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hover is not working on IE11 and Edge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46232707/hover-is-not-working-on-ie11-and-edge)

Comment: Same problem in Edge as well. Doesn’t seem to be a new issue -
 https://stackoverflow.com/q/38262353/1427878, plus several other Google hits. https://codepen.io/Zoxon/pen/LGaGKE has a JS solution that detects IE and applies a workaround.

Comment: It's seems there's some errors on Edge using CSS transitions, check it out https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/11690466/ (many issues has been open)

Comment: There is no fix for this issue at this moment so this is why I asked this question.

Comment: Issue report: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/16011476/